# Event category with Unique Pageview

Tags: google-analytics

When I tried to make a custom report having "Event Category" as dimensions and "Unique Pageviews" as metrics,
I could not add "Unique Pageviews".

I found in GA explorer that "Unique Pageviews" and "Event Category" is invalid combination.

But does anyone have a idea why "Unique Pageviews" doesn't work with "Event Category"?

Thanks

Comment: Because "Event" is a different hit type than "Pageview". You can have the same event on different pages (or multiple times on the same page), so the combination does not make really sense, and technically it would be a challenge to aggregate the data over the different hit types. Also, since this is not a programming question it's probably off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The "Unique Pageviews" metric is only incremented when a specific page is viewed for the first time in the session. Your event may not happen when user was viewing the page for the first time.

> Unique Pageviews are generated by the same user during the same
>   session. A unique pageview represents the number of sessions during
>   which that page was viewed one or more times.

In other words, Unique Pageviews is a session count which included this specific page.

It is better explained here:
 [Pageviews, and Unique Pageviews in Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1257084?hl=en)